# How to connect/bind two tables using Spring MVC and hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

My English is not very well, so sorry for mistakes.

I'am using a Spring, Spring MVC, Hibernate, Spring Data.

I have two entities Customer and CustomerDetails I would like to connect/bind them.
I'am using @OneToOne annotation, but I have no idea how to set a customer for CusomerDetails and vice versa. I found that I should create Customer and CustomerDetails in controller, and there connect them, but it is not working and I think that it is a bad approach. Anyone  knows How should it looks?

Thanks for help.

Customer class:

```
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="customer")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="customer_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="address")
    private String address;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private CustomerDetails customerDetails;

    public Customer() {
    }

    public Customer(CustomerDetails customerDetails)
    {
        this.customerDetails=customerDetails;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }



    public CustomerDetails getCustomerDetails() {
        return customerDetails;
    }

    public void setCustomerDetails(CustomerDetails customerDetails) {
        this.customerDetails = customerDetails;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Customer [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", email=" + email + ", address=" + address
                + ", customerDetails=" + customerDetails + "]";
    }

}
```

CustomerDetails:

```
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="customer_details")
public class CustomerDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="surname")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="number")
    private int number;

    @OneToOne(cascade= {CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REFRESH})
    private Customer customer;




    public CustomerDetails() {

    }


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public Customer getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CustomerDetails [id=" + id + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", number=" + number + ", customer=" + customer
                + "]";
    }


}
```

Services:

```
import java.util.List;

import com.firstapp.entity.Customer;

public interface CustomerService {

    public List<Customer>getCustomers();

    public Customer getCustomer(int id);

    public void saveCustomer(Customer customer);

    public void deleteCustomer(int id);

    public List<Customer>search(String keyword);

}


public interface CustomerDetailsService {

    public List<CustomerDetails> getCustomers();

    public CustomerDetails getCustomer(int id);

    public void saveCustomer(CustomerDetails customer);

    public void deleteCustomer(int id);
}


@Service
public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository repo;

    public List<Customer> getCustomers() {
        return repo.findAll();
    }

    public Customer getCustomer(int id) {
        Optional<Customer>result= repo.findById(id);
        return result.get();
    }

    public void saveCustomer(Customer customer) {
        repo.save(customer);
    }

    public void deleteCustomer(int id) {
        repo.deleteById(id);
    }

    public List<Customer>search(String keyword)
    {
        return repo.search(keyword);
    }


}



import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.firstapp.entity.CustomerDetails;
import com.firstapp.repository.CustomerDetailsRepository;

@Service
public class CustomerDetailsServiceImpl implements CustomerDetailsService{

    @Autowired
    private CustomerDetailsRepository repo;

    public List<CustomerDetails> getCustomers() {
        return repo.findAll();
    }

    public CustomerDetails getCustomer(int id) {
        return repo.findById(id).get();
    }

    public void saveCustomer(CustomerDetails customer) {
        repo.save(customer);
    }

    public void deleteCustomer(int id) {
        repo.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

Repositories:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.firstapp.entity.Customer;

@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Integer> {

    @Query(value="SELECT c from Customer c where c.name LIKE '%'|| :keyword || '%'"
            + "OR c.email LIKE '%'|| :keyword || '%'"
            + "OR c.address LIKE '%'|| :keyword || '%'")
    public List<Customer>search(@Param("keyword")String keyword);
}


import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.firstapp.entity.CustomerDetails;

@Repository
public interface CustomerDetailsRepository extends JpaRepository<CustomerDetails, Integer> {

}
```

My controller:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import com.firstapp.entity.Customer;
import com.firstapp.entity.CustomerDetails;
import com.firstapp.service.CustomerDetailsService;
import com.firstapp.service.CustomerDetailsServiceImpl;
import com.firstapp.service.CustomerService;
import com.firstapp.service.CustomerServiceImpl;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/customer")public class CustomerController {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerService service;

    @Autowired
    private CustomerDetailsService serviceCD;

    @GetMapping("/home")public String home(Model model)
    {       
        List<Customer>customers=service.getCustomers();
        model.addAttribute("message","Hello from Spring MVC");  model.addAttribute("customers",customers);
        return "home-page";
    }

    @GetMapping("/showForm")
    public String showForm(Map<String,Object>model)
    {
        Customer customer=new Customer();
        CustomerDetails cd=new CustomerDetails();
        customer.setCustomerDetails(cd);
        model.put("customer",new Customer());
        model.put("customerDetails", cd);
        return "new-customer";
    }

    @PostMapping("/add")
    public String addCustomer(@ModelAttribute("customer") Customer customer)
    {
        service.saveCustomer(customer);
        return "redirect:/customer/addDetails";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/addDetails")
    public String addCustomerDetails(@ModelAttribute("customerDetails") CustomerDetails customerDt)
    {
        serviceCD.saveCustomer(customerDt);
        return "redirect:/customer/home";
    }



    @GetMapping("/edit")
    public String editCustomer(@RequestParam int id, Model model)
    {
        Customer customer=service.getCustomer(id);
        model.addAttribute("customer",customer);
        return "edit-customer";
    }

    @GetMapping("/delete")
    public String deleteCustomer(@RequestParam int id)
    {
        service.deleteCustomer(id);
        return "redirect:/customer/home";
    }

    @GetMapping("/search")
    public String search(@RequestParam String keyword,Model model)
    {
        List<Customer>customers=service.search(keyword);
        model.addAttribute("customers",customers);
        return "search-page";
    }
}
```

my jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" isELIgnored="false"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Customer registration</title>

</head>
<body>

<div align="center">
    <h2>New Customer</h2>

<form:form action="add" method="post" modelAttribute="customer">
<table>

<tr>
<td>Name:</td>
<td><form:input path="name"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>E-mail:</td>
<td><form:input path="email"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Address:</td>
<td><form:input path="address"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
</tr>


</table>

</form:form>

</div>

</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the CustomerDetails for Customer:

```
customer.setCustomerDetail(customerDetail);
customerDetail.setCustomer(customer);
```

It's enough. Spring JPA automatically sets references and id's between table entities.

In additional try to change model layer:

1) First what you should to change - add the `mappedBy` parameter with table name into '@OneToOne'
2) Use `@JoinColumn` for one of entity:

for Customer:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "customer")
@JoinColumn(name = "customer_details_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
```

for CustomerDetails:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "customer_detail")
```

in additional: try to save CustomerDetail entity into table after creating, but before saving a `Customer`.

PS
Does no matter technically where are you create entities - it is just patterns and SOLID principals.
All parameters in @OneToOne and @JoinColumn should be named as fields in entity and as tables. Once I had a very difficult and long resolving with this issue. So be precise.

Comment: In a controller? Is it a good approach?

something like this:

@GetMapping("/showForm")
    public String showForm(Map<String,Object>model)
    {
        Customer customer=new Customer();
        CustomerDetails cd=new CustomerDetails();
        customer.setCustomerDetails(cd);
        model.put("customer",new Customer());
        return "new-customer";
    }

? It is not working, it saves only Customer

Comment: Thanks for help, but it still isn't working. Anyway I found the solution. For interested people: you need to create new CustomerDetails object in addCustomer controller and there set customer for CustomerDetails and vice versa.